# Proof by induction: $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ versus $P(n-1) \implies P(n)$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

My understanding of proof by induction is that we first established a base case, say $n = 1 $, and then upon establishing that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$, we can conclude, by applying this fact an infinite number of times, that $P(n), \forall n$, since $1 \implies 2$, $2 \implies 3$, $3 \implies 4$, and so forth.

How can we reconcile this with inductive proofs that establish that $P(n-1) \implies P(n)$? If I took a base case, for example, of $n = 1$, then I'd have $P(0)$, which may not make any sense in the context. Would I need to take an $n = 2$ base case?

Comment: The starting point must be $0$ or $1$ according to your def of $\mathbb N$: either $0$ or $1$. The base case must consider the **first** element.

Comment: The induction step is: "for every $n$, if $P(n)$ then $P(s(n))$", where $s(n)$ is the *successor* of $n$; we may have not defined what is subtraction.

Comment: The base case is not always $n=1$ and depends on the statement, for example the base case for proving the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is $n=2$

Answer (score 2):

If $P(n)$ is defined only when $n\in\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, then, of course, we can't say that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):P(n-1)\implies P(n);$$it doesn't make sense. But we **can** say that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}):P(n-1)\implies P(n),$$which is *the same thing* as asserting that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):P(n)\implies P(n+1).$$

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand: suppose that the base case is $n = 1$, and I prove that $P(n-1) \implies P(n)$. Does this imply that $P(0)$ holds, or that $P(n)$ holds for any $n$ not including $1$?

Comment: The expression $P(n-1)\implies P(n)$ is meaningless without a quantifier. If you mean that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):P(n-1)\implies P(n)$, then this doesn't make sense, since $P(0)$ is undefined. If you mean $(\forall n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}):P(n-1)\implies P(n)$, everything is fine then.

Comment: Both of these quantifications now make sense to me, thank you. If I could ask one more question: is it true that the only time I would every want to assume $P(n-1)$ and prove $P(n)$ in an inductive proof is when I am only trying to prove the result for $n \geq 2$? Otherwise, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Why? As I wrote, the assertions$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):P(n)\implies P(n+1)$$and$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}):P(n-1)\implies P(n)$$mean the same thing. So, it's just a matter of taste.